Definition of good quantum LDPC code
I am a bit confused by the exact definition of a "good" quantum LDPC code.
I call $k$ the number of logical qubits, $n$ the number of physical qubits and $d$ the distance of the code.
I focus on stabilizer codes to simplify.
My understanding from this paper is that a quantum LDPC code is a code where:

Each generator in the stabilizer group acts on a finite number of qubits
Any physical qubit of the code is involved in a finite number of generators of the stabilizer group.

From the same paper, I understand that a good code is a code where: $k=\Theta(n)$ and $d=\Theta(n)$.
Hence a good quantum LDPC code combines the two definitions above.
Now, I'm unsure to really understand because of the following:
Clearly the surface code is LDPC but is not "good" because $d \propto \sqrt{n}$. However it is also said that for a surface code $k=\color{red}{1}$ when we increase $n$ (second column of the second paragraph of the paper).
I don't understand this statement. For any code, if I double my number of physical qubits, I can double the number of logical qubits (I combine two encoded logical qubits). It makes me doubt that I correctly understand the definitions.

My questions are:

Are my definitions of a "good" quantum code, and a quantum "LDPC" code correct?
Why $k \propto n$ isn't true for every code (as a worst-case scenario)?



Your definition is correct. Usually one talks about the rate of the code, i.e. k/n. Then, a good qLDPC is a code with linear distance, and also a constant rate when n goes to infinity (i.e. the number of logical qubits increases with the number of physical qubits, up to a numerical factor).

It is not true, in general, that increasing the number of physical qubits also increases the number of logical qubits.
In the surface code, increasing the number of physical qubits of a single code reduces the logical error rate, but the code still encodes one logical qubit.


It is true that you can double the number of physical qubits by creating two patches of different surface codes with distance d. That why when evaluating qLDPC codes, one really needs to compare to a k patches of surface codes and then deduce what is the overhead and how does the logical error rate affected.

Thanks. So the implicit assumption I was missing for the ratio $k/n$ is that we should consider a single encoding block to talk about this quantity in this context. That's right?

Exactly. Just note that it is not just technical. A "single encoding block" is actually what constitutes a code: it is the same code for n=10 and for n=20, but with more logical information.

Regarding your second question, it does seem that if I have an $[[n, k, d]]$ code, then by putting $m$ of these codes next to each other, I appear to have an $[[nm, km, d]]$ code. As you can see, $n \propto m$ and $k \propto m$, but if the underlying code doesn't have $n$ linear in $k$, then $\frac{nm}{km}$ clearly isn't a constant. In the surface code, for instance, $n \sim d^2$ and $k = 1$, so putting more code patches next to each other doesn't fix this.

This answer is interesting, and I would be interested by more insight (I could give a bounty to it). Basically why can't I simply say that grouping $k$ patches of surface code together also gives an $[[n,k,d]]$ code, with $n/k$ being constant. For me this is technically valid (I double the patches I double the number of logical qubits). I agree though that $d \sim \sqrt{n}$ (hence it is not a good LDPC). But depending on how I combine the code, the ratio physical/logical can always be put constant. Don't you agree?

I think the ambiguity arises from what we mean by "constant" encoding rate. This is typically in relation to an increased distance codeblock. Any distance-preserving can be trivially prescribed a constant $n/k$ as you detailed, so I believe it is implicit that  we mean $n/k$ when $n, k$ are some functions of $d$ (or vice versa). It's just an example of abridged and potentially sloppy language.
